# Call stored procedure for each row from select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a bunch of records from my select statement. I have to call certain stored procedure for each row from that select. I know this be done with cursors (I've found answers about this on SO - but they are all very old). I am curious whether there is some other possibility today, in the modern version of SQL server?

My select:

```
SELECT USER_KEY, USER_WHK FROM BAUSER WHERE USER_STA = '1'
```

My insert:

```
EXEC sp_BAUSCA_BASE 
  @iUSCA_KEY = NULL
, @iCAET_KEY = 150000003
, @iUSER_KEY = --user key from select
, @iENTE_KEY = 110000001
, @dUSCA_DAT = GETDATE()
, @cUSCA_STA = '1'
, @cUSCA_SRT = '1'
, @iUserId = 160000230
, @cTask = '2'
```

Comment: What are you doing inside that sp that cannot be done in SQL? Ideally you should just insert from select instead of using a cursor. Unless of course you are doing something very funky in the sproc like calling a crypto api of something...

Comment: PRoblem is USCA_KEY - it is generated inside stored procedure, by calling another stored proc.

Answer (score 4):

You can archive this requirement by using [Cursor](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/01/cursor-in-sql-server-with-syntax-and-example.html), I have made a demo for your this might helps you.

For more information about the cursor, you can visit this [link](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/01/cursor-in-sql-server-with-syntax-and-example.html).

**Demo**

```
DECLARE 
@iUSCA_KEY  NVARCHAR(50) ,
@iCAET_KEY  NVARCHAR(50) ,
@iUSER_KEY  NVARCHAR(50) ,
@iENTE_KEY  NVARCHAR(50) ,
@dUSCA_DAT  DATETIME,
@cUSCA_STA  NVARCHAR(50) ,
@cUSCA_SRT  NVARCHAR(50) ,
@iUserId    INT,
@cTask      NVARCHAR(50) 

DECLARE MY_data CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT  
    iUSCA_KEY,  
    iCAET_KEY , 
    iUSER_KEY , 
    iENTE_KEY , 
    dUSCA_DAT,  
    cUSCA_STA,  
    cUSCA_SRT , 
    iUserId ,   
    cTask      
    FROM    BAUSER WHERE USER_STA = '1'


OPEN MY_data
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_data INTO @iUSCA_KEY,@iCAET_KEY,@iUSER_KEY,@iENTE_KEY,@dUSCA_DAT,@cUSCA_STA,@cUSCA_SRT,@iUserId,@cTask  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

       EXEC sp_BAUSCA_BASE 
            @iUSCA_KEY = @iUSCA_KEY
            , @iCAET_KEY = @iCAET_KEY
            , @iUSER_KEY = @iUSER_KEY
            , @iENTE_KEY = @iENTE_KEY
            , @dUSCA_DAT = @dUSCA_DAT
            , @cUSCA_STA = @cUSCA_STA
            , @cUSCA_SRT = @cUSCA_SRT
            , @iUserId = @iUserId
            , @cTask = @cTask

        FETCH NEXT FROM MY_data INTO  @iUSCA_KEY,@iCAET_KEY,@iUSER_KEY,@iENTE_KEY,@dUSCA_DAT,@cUSCA_STA,@cUSCA_SRT,@iUserId,@cTask  
    END
CLOSE MY_data
DEALLOCATE MY_data
```

Comment: So even today there is not other mechanism available other than cursor?

Comment: @FrenkyB, that's right. I just make notice that such cursors shall be always declared LOCAL FAST_FORWARD for optimal performance and lowest retention lock. Regards and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm talking under correction, but as I understand it, a loop is bit more resource intensive.

However, you can accomplish it with a loop as well.

Note that I have not been able to test it as I don't have source data and the SP's you have, but I'm sure the script is bulletproof:

```
DECLARE     @LOOP       INT
,           @iUSCAKEY   INT
,           @iCAETKEY   INT
,           @iUSERKEY   INT
,           @iENTEKEY   INT
,           @cUSCASTA   VARCHAR(10)
,           @cUSCASRT   VARCHAR(10)
,           @iUserId    BIGINT
,           @cTask  VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE   (
                            ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
                        ,   iUSCA_KEY   INT
                        ,   iCAET_KEY   INT
                        ,   iUSER_KEY   INT
                        ,   iENTE_KEY   INT
                        ,   cUSCA_STA   VARCHAR(10)
                        ,   cUSCA_SRT   VARCHAR(10)
                        ,   iUserId     BIGINT
                        ,   cTask       VARCHAR(100)

                        )

INSERT INTO @TBL        (
                            iUSCA_KEY
                        ,   iCAET_KEY
                        ,   iUSER_KEY
                        ,   iENTE_KEY
                        ,   cUSCA_STA
                        ,   cUSCA_SRT
                        ,   iUserId
                        ,   cTask

                        )
                        SELECT
                            iUSCA_KEY
                        ,   iCAET_KEY
                        ,   iUSER_KEY
                        ,   iENTE_KEY
                        ,   cUSCA_STA
                        ,   cUSCA_SRT
                        ,   iUserId
                        ,   cTask
                        FROM BAUSER
                        WHERE USER_STA = '1'


        SELECT @LOOP = MIN(ID) FROM @TBL
        WHILE @LOOP IS NOT NULL

            BEGIN

                    SELECT
                        @iUSCAKEY   =   iUSCA_KEY
                    ,   @iCAETKEY   =   iCAET_KEY
                    ,   @iUSERKEY   =   iUSER_KEY
                    ,   @iENTEKEY   =   iENTE_KEY
                    ,   @cUSCASTA   =   cUSCA_STA
                    ,   @cUSCASRT   =   cUSCA_SRT
                    ,   @iUserId    =   iUserId
                    ,   @cTask      =   cTask
                    FROM    @TBL
                    WHERE   ID  =   @LOOP

                    EXEC sp_BAUSCA_BASE 
                      @iUSCA_KEY    =   @iUSCAKEY
                    , @iCAET_KEY    =   @iCAETKEY
                    , @iUSER_KEY    =   @iUSERKEY
                    , @iENTE_KEY    =   @iENTEKEY
                    , @dUSCA_DAT    =   GETDATE()
                    , @cUSCA_STA    =   @cUSCASTA
                    , @cUSCA_SRT    =   @cUSCASRT
                    , @iUserId      =   @iUserId
                    , @cTask        =   @cTask

                SELECT @LOOP = MIN(ID) FROM @TBL WHERE ID > @LOOP

            END
```

Let me know if it worked.